# What happens when GetTickCount() wraps?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

If a thread is doing something like this:

```
const DWORD interval = 20000;
DWORD ticks = GetTickCount();
while(true)
{
    DoTasksThatTakeVariableTime();

    if( GetTickCount() - ticks > interval )
    {
        DoIntervalTasks();
        ticks = GetTickCount();
    }
}
```

Eventually, ticks is going to wrap when the value doesn't fit in a DWORD.

I've been discussing this with a colleague. One of us believes the code will still behave 'nicely' when the wrap occurs, because the subtraction operation will also wrap. The other of us, believes it won't always work, especially if the interval is large.

Who's right, and why?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're really asking is what happens when you subtract a large DWORD from a small one. You and your colleague could have just written a program to find out. GetTickCount is irrelevant to that.

Comment: I did experiment with calc.exe, set to hex mode using dword size. And the results looked like it would behave nicely... however, my colleague wasn't convinced it would work in all cases, thus the question. GetTickCount is relevant, Jon Skeet's already pointed out we  might use GetTickCount64 instead

Comment: GetTickCount64() just changes the scale of the problem to wrapping after something like 200 billion days.... are you sure your code won't run that long?  ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx):

> The elapsed time is stored as a DWORD
>   value. Therefore, the time will wrap
>   around to zero if the system is run
>   continuously for 49.7 days. To avoid
>   this problem, use GetTickCount64.
>   Otherwise, check for an overflow
>   condition when comparing times.

However, DWORD is unsigned - so you should be okay. 0 - "very big number" = "small number" (assuming you don't have any overflow checking active, of course). I had a previous edit which suggested you'd get a negative number, but that was before I took into account that DWORD is unsigned.

You'll still have a problem if the operation takes *just under* 49.7 days though. That may not be an issue for you ;)

One way to test would be to stub out the `GetTickCount()` method so you could write unit tests where you explicitly make it wrap. Then again, if you're really only doubting the arithmetic part, you can easily write unit tests for that :) Really, the fact that the number is coming from a system clock is pretty much irrelevant so long as you know the behaviour when it wraps - and that's specified in the documentation.

Comment: Note: 49.7 days is likely when it overflows. i.e. 4294967295ms is 49.7102696181 days

Answer (score 12):

Nothing bad happens, as long as:

- You subtract `DWORD`s, rather than converting to some other type first.
- Nothing you're trying to time takes longer than 49.7 days.

This is because unsigned arithmetic overflow is well-defined in C, and wrapping behavior does exactly what we want.

```
DWORD t1, t2;
DWORD difference;

t1 = GetTickCount();
DoSomethingTimeConsuming();
t2 = GetTickCount();
```

`t2 - t1` will produce the correct the value, even if `GetTickCount` wraps around.  Just don't convert `t2` and `t1` to some other type (e.g. `int` or `double`) before doing the subtraction.

This won't work if the programming language treats overflow as an error.  It also won't work if `DoSomethingTimeConsuming()` takes longer than 49.7 days.  You can't tell just by looking at `t2` and `t1` how many times `GetTickCount` wrapped around, unfortunately.

---

Let's start with the the usual case, where no wraparound comes into play:

```
t1 = 13487231
t2 = 13492843
```

Here, `t2 - t1 = 5612`, which means the operation took about five seconds.

Now consider an operation that takes a short amount of time, but where `GetTickCount` did wrap around:

```
t1 = 4294967173
t2 = 1111
```

The operation took 1234ms, but the timer wrapped around, and `1111 - 4294967173` is the bogus value of `-4294966062`.  What ever will we do?

Well, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, the result of subtraction wraps around, too:

```
(DWORD)-4294966062 == (DWORD)1234
```

Finally, consider the edge case where an operation takes *nearly* 2<sup>32</sup> milliseconds, but not quite:

```
t1 = 2339189280
t2 = 2339167207
```

Here, `GetTickCount` wrapped around, and came right back around where it was.

Now `t2 - t1` yields the bogus-looking value of `4294945223`.  That's because that's the amount of time the operation actually took!

In general:

```
(base + offset) - base ≡ offset mod 2^32
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to test what happens when `GetTickCount()` wraps, you could enable Application Verifier's TimeRollOver test.

From [Using Application Verifier Within Your Software Development Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480483.aspx):

> **TimeRollOver** forces the GetTickCount and TimeGetTime APIs to roll over faster than they normally would. This allows applications to test their handling of time rollover more easily.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest calculating the actual elapsed period between the two ticks, not relying on the compiler to handle it for you:

```
const DWORD interval = 20000;

#define TICKS_DIFF(prev, cur) ((cur) >= (prev)) ? ((cur)-(prev)) : ((0xFFFFFFFF-(prev))+1+(cur))

DWORD ticks = GetTickCount();
while(true)
{
    DoTasksThatTakeVariableTime();

    DWORD curticks = GetTickCount();
    if( TICKS_DIFF(ticks, curticks) > interval )
    {
        DoIntervalTasks();
        ticks = GetTickCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran across that problem recently. The code I was working on used GetTickCount() in a bunch of places to determine if the program was spending too much time on a particular task and if so it would time-out that task and re-schedule it for later execution. What would happen is that if the GetTickCount() wrapped during one of the measurement periods, it would cause the code to time-out prematurely. This was a service which runs constantly, so every 49 days, it would have a slight hiccup.

I fixed it by writing a timer class which used GetTickCount() internally but detected when the value wrapped and compensated for it.

Answer (score 1):

Surely You need to handle this tick wrap problem.

Linux kernel handles such tick wrap problem with following trick:

> #define time_after(a,b) ((long)(b) - (long)(a) < 0))

The idea is cast unsigned to signed and compare their value, then only if the |a-b|<2^30, then the wrap does not influence the result.

You can have a try with this trick and get learn why it works.

Since DWORD is also unsigned int, this trick should also works for windows.

So you code could be sth like:

> const DWORD interval = 20000;
>
> DWORD ticks = GetTickCount() + interval;
>
> while(true)  {
>
> ```
> DoTasksThatTakeVariableTime();
>
> if(time_after(ticks, GetTickCount())
> {
>     DoIntervalTasks();
>     ticks = GetTickCount() + interval;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Only if interval less than 0x2^30, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could test it ;) - I have a simple test application here which will launch an app and hook `GetTickCount()` in it so that you can control it from the GUI of the test app. I wrote it as stubbing out the `GetTickCount()` calls in some apps isn't that easy.

TickShifter is free and is available here:  http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2006/04/tickshifter-v02.html

I wrote it whilst writing a series of articles on Test Driven Development which used some code that used `GetTickCount()` in a broken way.

Articles are available here in case you're interested: http://www.lenholgate.com/blog/2004/05/practical-testing.html

However, in summary, your code will work...

Answer (score 1):

This article helped me, but I think there is a bug in:

```
#define TICKS_DIFF(prev, cur) ((cur) >= (prev)) ? ((cur)-(prev)) : ((0xFFFFFFFF-(prev))+(cur))
```

When I tested this at the wrap around point, I found it was off by 1.

What worked for me was:

```
define TICKS_DIFF(prev, cur) ((cur) >= (prev)) ? ((cur)-(prev)) : ((0xFFFFFFFF-(prev))+(cur)+1)
```

Comment: Or have you tried the simpler equivalent:  TICKS_DIFF(prev,cur) ((cur)-(prev))       It works even with wrap around.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is completely irrelevant almost 11 years later and with the inclusion of GetTickCount64() from Vista onwards, but here is a little bit of helper code I've had in my tookit since forever which I used to use back when this was an issue.

```
inline DWORD GetElapsed(DWORD from, DWORD to = ::GetTickCount())
{
  if (from < to)        //check for wrap around condition
      return (to - from);
  else
      return ((0xFFFFFFFFL - from) + 1 + to);
}
```

Usage

```
DWORD start = ::GetTickCount();

// Some time later

DWORD elapsed = GetElapsed(start);
```

The worry wasn't that your operation might take longer that 49.7 days, but that the tick counter might roll over during your operation, thus making your elapsed time calculation unreliable.

Of course, all irrelevant now because of GetTickCount64()